# Can I validate a header value in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I use the Serverless Framework to build and deploy my lambdas.

There's a service I use that sends a secret string in a specific header e.g. `X-Secret`, and this string is always the same e.g. `FOOBAR`.

I don't want to create a Lambda authoriser just to compare it.

Can API Gateway natively filter out requests based on header values?

In this case, can it block requests that don't have the header `X-Secret` set to `FOOBAR`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, sorry, I've update my question.

Comment: If you always set the header to the same value, then why bother checking the value? Just check for the presence of the header using an API Gateway Request Validator.

Comment: @BrettDonald I think what they mean is that they'd always be checking the header against the same value, not that the header value could always be the same if that makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can API Gateway natively filter out requests based on header values?

Unfortunately, Amazon API Gateway doesn't support natively checking header values. The closest feature would be [API Gateway request validators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html) which won't work as they can only check if the header exists, and not the header value.

The only other option I can think of is using [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/), which [only supports REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html#http-api-vs-rest.differences.security) and has an 8 KB limit:

> You can also **create rules that match a specified string** or a regular expression pattern **in HTTP headers**, method, query string, URI, and the request body (limited to the first 8 KB).

If possible, I would recommend just going with a simple Python Lambda authoriser. WAF would probably be [more expensive](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/pricing/) and overkill.

```py
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    token = event['headers']['X-Secret']
    if token == 'FOOBAR':
        return generate_policy('user', 'Allow', event['methodArn'])
    else:
        return generate_policy('user', 'Deny', event['methodArn'])

def generate_policy(principal_id, effect, resource):
    policy = {
        "principalId": principal_id,
        "policyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                    "Effect": effect,
                    "Resource": resource
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    return policy
```

---

However, for whatever reason, you may still want to go ahead with AWS WAF.

You need to define a web ACL, associate it with your API Gateway and create a suitable rule for your web ACL.

We'll do this in AWS CloudFormation (CFN) as the Serverless framework is basically [a wrapper](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources) around CFN. Anything that can be defined in CloudFormation is supported by the Serverless Framework.

Two options:

- Configure web ACL to *allow by default* & create a rule with a condition to block any request that *doesn't* have the header `X-Secret` set to `FOOBAR`
- Configure web ACL to *block by default* & create a rule with a condition to allow any request that *does* have the header `X-Secret` set to `FOOBAR` (objectively easier logic to visualise and implement)

We'll go with option 2.

---

**We need a [web ACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl.html) first.**

Essentially, it's a container for rules. The Web ACL as a whole governs how your AWS resource i.e. your API Gateway responds to web requests based on the rules it contains.

It needs [4 things](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html) to be defined:

1. *What is this web ACL called?* (`Name`)

We'll just call it `MyAcl`. Note the CloudFormation docs are incorrect in saying it is not required and I've submitted a feedback request to fix this - it *is* needed by the API and thus CloudFormation.

2. *What is this web ACL for?* (`Scope`)

We'll specify `REGIONAL`, as the only other option is `CLOUDFRONT` which is only for Amazon CloudFront distributions.

3. *If none of the defined rules match, what's the default action?* ([`DefaultAction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-defaultaction.html))

In this case, we're going with a single rule that *allows* anything with the `X-Secret` set to `FOOBAR` so we want to *block everything else*. We'll set this to [`BlockAction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-blockaction.html) to block requests that don't match our rule by default. If you went with the inverse scenario, you'd need to inverse this.

4. Should metrics be sent to Amazon CloudWatch and/or should requests be sampled? ([`VisbilityConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-visibilityconfig.html))

In this case, we need neither of these features so we'll set `CloudWatchMetricsEnabled` and `SampledRequestsEnabled` both to `false`. We also need to weirdly still set `MetricName` to something even if it's disabled (forever a mystery) so we'll set it to `RandomMetricName`.

You also will eventually define `Rules`, a list of [`Rule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-rule.html) resources. Pretty self-explanatory in that it will contain your rule(s) but this isn't *strictly* needed at the time of creation.

---

**Then, we need a WAF rule, as we have a container but no *stuff*.**

A [WAF rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rules.html) lets you precisely target the requests that you want to allow or block by specifying the exact condition(s) that you want it to watch for.

It needs [5 things](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-rule.html) to be defined:

1. What's the name of this rule? (`Name`)

We'll just name it 'MyHeaderRule`.

2. What is the priority of this rule? (`Priority`)

In this case, we have one rule so we could set this to any number. We'll just set this to 0 but note that when you have more than one rule, priorities are really important as they determine [processing order](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-processing-order.html).

3. What is this rule doing? (`Statement`)

Our rule statement will define a string match search on the `X-Secret` header. The [AWS WAF console & the developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-string-match.html) call it a *string match rule statement* while the [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_ByteMatchStatement.html) and [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-bytematchstatement.html) call it a *ByteMatchStatement*.

4. Should AWS WAF allow or block the request on a rule match? ([`Action`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-ruleaction.html))

We'll set this to [`AllowAction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-allowaction.html) to allow on rule match, as the ACL will block everything else based on our `DefaultAction`. Note for completeness sake, this doesn't always need to be set depending on if you're using rule groups or not, and sometimes you might need to set `OverrideAction` but in this case, we do need it.

5. Should metrics be sent to Amazon CloudWatch and/or should requests be sampled? ([`VisbilityConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-visibilityconfig.html))

As above.

---

**Finally, we need our actual rule statement - a `ByteMatchStatement`.**

It also has [4 things](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-bytematchstatement.html) we need to define:

1. What should the statement check a match against? ([`FieldToMatch`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-fieldtomatch.html))

We want to check (a header in) the headers. However, as per the docs for [`Headers`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-headers.html), since we only want to inspect a single header, we have a mini shortcut of just setting this to a [`SingleHeader`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-singleheader.html) object with a `Name` value of `X-Secret`. This is easier than defining a more complex `Headers` object.

2. Where should the statement check for a match or more informally, what is the search type? ([`PositionalConstraint`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-bytematchstatement.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-bytematchstatement-positionalconstraint))

We want an exact match (*Exactly matches string* in the console) so we will set this to `EXACTLY`.

3. What is the value for matching to be done against? (`SearchString` or `SearchStringBase64`)

We will set `SearchString` to `FOOBAR`, as `FOOBAR` is a base64-unencoded value.

4. Should AWS WAF perform any transformation on the value of `FieldToMatch`, before it checks for a match? ([`TextTransformations`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-wafv2-webacl-texttransformation.html))

As per docs, this is usually done to reverse unusual formatting that attackers use in web requests in an effort to bypass detection. In this case, we don't want any transformations so we'll just set our `Type` to `NONE` and `Priority` to `0`.

Our rule in JSON would look like this:

```json
{
  "Name": "MyHeaderRule",
  "Priority": 0,
  "Action": {
    "Allow": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": false,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": false,
    "MetricName": "RandomMetricName"
  },
  "Statement": {
    "ByteMatchStatement": {
      "FieldToMatch": {
        "SingleHeader": {
          "Name": "X-Secret"
        }
      },
      "PositionalConstraint": "EXACTLY",
      "SearchString": "FOOBAR",
      "TextTransformations": [
        {
          "Type": "NONE",
          "Priority": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Bringing all of the above together with the [`serverless-associate-waf`](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-associate-waf) plugin, we get something like this:**

```yaml
plugins:
  - serverless-associate-waf

custom:
  wafAssociation:
    name: ${self:resources.Resources.WAFWebACL.Properties.Name}
    version: V2

resources:
  WAFWebACL:
  Type: 'AWS::WAFv2::WebACL'
  Properties:
    Name: MyAcl
    Scope: REGIONAL
    DefaultAction:
      Block: {}
    VisibilityConfig:
      SampledRequestsEnabled: false
      CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: false
      MetricName: RandomMetricName
    Rules:
      - Name: MyHeaderRule
        Priority: 0
        Statement:
          ByteMatchStatement:
            FieldToMatch:
              SingleHeader:
                Name: X-Secret
            PositionalConstraint: EXACTLY
            SearchString: FOOBAR
            TextTransformations:
              - Priority: 0
                Type: NONE
        Action:
          Allow: {}
        VisibilityConfig:
          SampledRequestsEnabled: false
          CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: false
          MetricName: RandomMetricName
```